# Apache PredictionIO Similar Product Engine Template Install Problem

Tags: apache-spark, prediction, predictionio, recommendation-engine

I have installed apache predictionio according to the document here:

http://predictionio.apache.org/install/install-sourcecode/

No problem, it works. I added the necessary data.

But I am having trouble installing the Similar Product Engine Template.

Exactly I proceeded according to the document here:

I applied all my steps one by one. Many times.

My Java version:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_265" OpenJDK Runtime
> Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2 ~ 18.04-b01) OpenJDK
> 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)

My OS:

> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Release: 18.04
> Codename: bionic

I came up to this step.

> pio build --verbose

Then on this step, I'm having trouble

> pio train

During this step I get the following errors and more:

```
[ERROR] [Executor] Exception in task 0.0 in stage 605.0 (TID 171)
[ERROR] [SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler] Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 171,5,main]
[WARN] [TaskSetManager] Lost task 0.0 in stage 605.0 (TID 171, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3037)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1598)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2366)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2290)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2148)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1647)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2366)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2290)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2148)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1647)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:441)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

full logs:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zyzP9BGRXt/

Answer (score 0):

When I increased the ram the problem was resolved.